# it would jeopardize Turkey's purchase of Lockheed Martin Corp F-35 fighter jets and possibly result in the United States imposing sanctions

Tags: grammaticality

They have also said it would jeopardize Turkey's purchase of Lockheed Martin Corp F-35 fighter jets and possibly result in the United States imposing sanctions.

In this sentence why there is no  apostrophes after united states in third line

Comment: Because there is no possessive.

Answer (score 0):

Placing an apostrophe after the United States in this sentence would be either ungrammatical ("and possibly result in the United States is imposing sanctions") or illogical ("and possibly result in the USA's imposing sanctions", which refers to something that the USA would have already, namely, imposing sanctions -- however, the sentence makes it clear that sanctions have not been imposed yet and are purely hypothetical).

Furthermore, in this context *imposing* is a verb, not an adjective (unlike, for example, "Kate's imposing room mate").

You could paraphrase this sentence: "...and possibly cause the United States to impose sanctions". I hope this makes it clearer why an apostrophe wouldn't be needed in either sentence.